# How to force developers use only 'yyyy' instead of 'YYYY' in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Since `YYYY` is week-based year and `yyyy` is yearly, we need any of these:

1. Force developers to never enter `YYYY` in `SimpleDateFormat("*YYYY*")` in code OR
2. Write a test case, which will scan the code and inform user in case they used `SimpleDateFormat` with `YYYY` to correct it.

We are trying Sonarqube custom rules. And scan the project during build.
Need to know if there is any other way we can force it during development or during git commit to Bitbucket.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
```

We need in such scenario or any scenario where developer uses "YYYY" to block it or convert it to "yyyy".

Comment: Semi-related: You should also get your developers not to use `SimpleDateFormat`, as this is legacy.  You should be using the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: @JoeC *Semi*-related? This is both on-topic and important!

Comment: If you care about enforcing `yyyy` over `YYYY`, why not enforce `dd` over `DD`, and `MM` over `mm`? Instead, why not **teach** your developers to write good code.

Comment: "We need in such scenario or any scenario where developer uses "YYYY" to block it or convert it to "yyyy"." Those kind of things should emit a warning. "Blocking it" is shortsighted. Converting it is against uh, about all good development practices including the principle or least surprise. I'd warn or fire somebody implementing it in a code validation utility, you don't get to mess with the code base from such a utility *period*.